# Spring Security - Custom JSON Message instead showing Login page

Tags: rest, spring-security, extjs4.1, spring-security-acl

I would like to get your valuable feedback on the below.
I am stuck in processing Spring-Security. I know that when i login to through form-login, the login-processing-url will be triggered and the page is redirected to spring security login.

But is it possible to cast a CUSTOM JSON Message when I haven't logged in to my application but about trying to access any API URL via REST. Your help would be much appreciated.!

I am using ExtJS for UI Login and Spring as RESTful service

Wondering to integrate this two view (Spring login view and my custom ExtJS login view)

```
<security:http  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"  use-expressions='true' >
        <security:form-login login-processing-url="/login" always-use-default-target="true" 
                             default-target-url="/user/authen" username-parameter="uid" password-parameter="password"
                             authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"   />


        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll" />
        <security:access-denied-handler  error-page="/login/accessDenied"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" />
        <security:http-basic/>
    </security:http>
    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/login/badCredentials</prop>
                <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/login/credentialsExpired</prop>
                <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/login/accountLocked</prop>
                <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException">/login/accountDisabled</prop>
                <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.AccessDeniedException">/login/accessDenied</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

- R.R. Vigneshwaran